# Java Factory patterns

Tags: java, factory, factory-pattern

Here is a factory "inner class?" from the Java Jung graph package:

```
   Factory<Graph<String, Integer>> graphFactory = new Factory<Graph<String, Integer>>()
   {
       public Graph<String, Integer> create()
       {
           return new SparseMultigraph<String, Integer>();
       }
   };
```

What I want to know is what programming language concept is the above? Especially what is this concept in Java? Is the above an inner class? It is clearly not a method. It seems odd to me because it constructs a Factory object and then has braces with a semicolon at the end with a method to create a graph.

Comment: The word is `Anonymous Inner Class`. Now you can start the google process to learn more about them

Comment: It is an anonymous Inner class with a function inside it.

Comment: You could ask what is the advantage of having Anonymous Inner Class for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an anonyous inner class. The above code creates a subclass of the `Factory` class (or a class implementing the `Factory` interface), overrides its `create()` method, calls its constructor, and assigns the result to the `graphFactory` variable.

Answer (score 3):

It is an **anonymous inner class**.

Comment: I think answer for the question is this.

Comment: @DanielM. Why? It answers the question.

Comment: @TonyEnnis yeah it is an answer but really short. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's an anonymous inner class concept.In layman terms,it can also be called an unnamed class.There is always a debate on the use of such classes against inheritance.Usually,if there is a one time usage requirement of a child class,then anonymous classes are more handy than inherited classes.

Answer (score 0):

As per the post it seems that you are aware that it is the concept of anonymous class in java that you are talking about.
Now since you are questioning y this :
The answer is that , as the name implies the class has no name, hence in a single step
 class declaration 
 the creation of an instance of the class
is complete. Due to this reason use of anonymous class save time and effort for creating a .java file. :)
As a rule anonymous class must implement all the abstract methods in the super class or the interface and should use all the default constructor of the super class.